# Android radio button group

Tags: android, android-layout

Can I get a `RadioButton` group in the following way?

```
x x x
x x x
x x x
```

Now I am getting it all in one line - either vertical or horizontal:

```
x x x x x x    or   x
                    x
                    x
                    x
                    x
                    x
```

In horizontal its going to the next line but its not in fixed position.

Below code is just to meet with the standards of posting.

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/calradioGroup4.1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioNONE"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="None" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="0-5" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="11-15" />
```

Comment: Use three radiogroups, one on top of the other, with a relativelayout.

Comment: But that doesn't really solve the issue as it hard-codes to three rows. I would suggest initialising RadioGroups dynamically, then you can specify row count depending on the data you have.

Comment: eh, i just used 3 groups, one beside the other! thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/r_A"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_A0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/gr_icon"
            android:text="A0"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_A1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/gr_icon"
            android:text="A1"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_B0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/gr_icon"
            android:text="B0"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_B1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/gr_icon"
            android:text="B1"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_C0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/gr_icon"
            android:text="C0"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_C1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/gr_icon"
            android:text="C1"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_D0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/gr_icon"
            android:text="D0"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_E0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/gr_icon"
            android:text="E1"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>
```